# Insert image in python web.py

Tags: python, html, web.py

I have a file test1.py. I am using web.py to display it in a webpage.

```
    import web

    urls = ('/', 'hello','/bye', 'bye')

    app = web.application(urls, globals(), True)

    class hello:
      def GET(self):
         return """<html>
         <head>
         </head>
          <body>
            <img src="smile.png" alt="SAP Logo" width="500px" height="100px"/>
           </body></html>"""
```

However, when run it will display:

```
127.0.0.1:59558 - - [28/Sep/2015 15:52:32] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 200 OK
127.0.0.1:59558 - - [28/Sep/2015 15:52:32] "HTTP/1.1 GET smile.png" - 404 Not Found
```

Image is placed in Desktop.

Comment: If the image is placed on the desktop, does that mean that the servers' folder root is also on the desktop?

Comment: Where have you told web.py how to serve your image from the desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Create a "static" folder in your project root, copy your "smile.png" to that folder. Now change the src value of the img tag:

```
<img src="/static/smile.png" alt="SAP Logo" width="500px" height="100px"/>
```

You should see your smile.png in the brower now, for more info on serving static files in web.py, go visit "http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles".